# Eclipse error: Get "Source attachment path for IClasspathEntry must be absolute" error twice

Tags: android, eclipse, parsing, sdk, eclipse-classpath

I have been trying to fix this error for sometime, as I can't compile any of my projects because anything my project's code uses that is part of the sdk comes up as an error in eclipse. I have tried moving my workspace folder around, deleting the sdk and eclipse folders and then replacing them with newly downloaded folders. But I keep getting the same error.

[image: window with the error that pops up]

Here are the details for the "Android SDK Content Loader" error

```
parseSdkContent failed
Source attachment path '\Users\lincoln\Desktop\android\sdk\sources\android-19' for IClasspathEntry must be absolute
```

Here are the details for the "Loading data for Android 4.4.2" error

```
Parsing Data for android-19 failed
Source attachment path '\Users\lincoln\Desktop\android\sdk\sources\android-19' for IClasspathEntry must be absolute
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So I copied the projects to a completely new workspace that I made,  and loaded that work space and that fixed it.